# CKFinder - browse server - getting system error message

Tags: php, ckfinder

I did some modifications (which I then reverted) in config.php for CKFinder (2.02 I think), however as I just did them quick in dirty in Notepad, it seems like it ruined my formatting which caused issues for the program.

Now when I try to "browse server" I get "system error"

I fixed the formatting (as far as I can tell) in the file and I'm not seeing any explicit code errors, but I'm hoping maybe you guys can notice anything I might have missed.

I've also tried uncommenting out this section:

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

With no luck.

Anyway, here is the code:

```
<?php

/*
* ### CKFinder : Configuration File - Basic Instructions 
* 
* In a generic usage case, the following tasks must be done to configure 
* CKFinder: 
*     1. Check the $baseUrl and $baseDir variables; 
*     2. If available, paste your license key in the "LicenseKey" setting; 
*     3. Create the CheckAuthentication() function that enables CKFinder for authenticated users; 
* 
* Other settings may be left with their default values, or used to control 
* advanced features of CKFinder. 
*/
// LicenseKey : Paste your license key here. If left blank, CKFinder will be
// fully functional, in demo mode.

$config['LicenseName'] = '';
$config['LicenseKey'] = '';

/* 
Uncomment lines below to enable PHP error reporting and displaying PHP errors.
Do not do this on a production server. Might be helpful when debugging why CKFinder does not work as expected.
*/

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);

/*
To make it easy to configure CKFinder, the $baseUrl and $baseDir can be used.

Those are helper variables used later in this config file.
*/

/*
$baseUrl : the base path used to build the final URL for the resources handledin CKFinder. If empty, the default value (/userfiles/) is used.

Examples:   

$baseUrl = 'http://example.com/ckfinder/files/';

$baseUrl = '/userfiles/';

ATTENTION: The trailing slash is required.
*/

/*

$baseUrl = '/ckfinder/userfiles/';

*/

$baseUrl = '/ckfinder/userfiles/';

/*
$baseDir : the path to the local directory (in the server) which points to theabove $baseUrl URL.

This is the path used by CKFinder to handle the files inthe server.

Full write permissions must be granted to this directory.

Examples:   

// You may point it to a directory directly:
    $baseDir = '/home/login/public_html/ckfinder/files/';   
    $baseDir = 'C:/SiteDir/CKFinder/userfiles/';

    // Or you may let CKFinder discover the path, based on $baseUrl.    

    // WARNING: resolveUrl() *will not work* if $baseUrl does not start with a slash ("/"), 

    // for example if $baseDir is set to  http://example.com/ckfinder/files/    $baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);

    ATTENTION: The trailing slash is required.
    */

    $baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);
    require_once '../../../../includes/filemanager.config.php';

    /*
    * ### Advanced Settings 
    */

    /*Thumbnails : thumbnails settings.
    All thumbnails will end up in the samedirectory, no matter the resource type.
    */

    $config['Thumbnails'] = Array(
    'url' => $baseUrl . '_thumbs',
    'directory' => $baseDir . '_thumbs',
    'enabled' => true,
    'directAccess' => false,
    'maxWidth' => 100,
    'maxHeight' => 100,
    'bmpSupported' => false,
    'quality' => 80);

    /*
    Set the maximum size of uploaded images.

    If an uploaded image is larger, itgets scaled down proportionally.

    Set to 0 to disable this feature.
    */

    $config['Images'] = Array(
    'maxWidth' => 1600,
    'maxHeight' => 1200,
    'quality' => 80);

    /*
    RoleSessionVar : the session variable name that CKFinder must use to retrievethe "role" of the current user.

    The "role", can be used in the "AccessControl"settings (bellow in this page).
    To be able to use this feature, you must initialize the session data byuncommenting the following "session_start()" call.
    */

    $config['RoleSessionVar'] = 'CKFinder_UserRole';

    //session_start();

    /*
    AccessControl : used to restrict access or features to specific folders.
    Many "AccessControl" entries can be added.

    All attributes are optional.Subfolders inherit their default settings from their parents' definitions.
    - The "role" attribute accepts the special '*' value, which means     "everybody".
    - The "resourceType" attribute accepts the special value '*', which   means "all resource types".

    */

    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
    'role' => '*',
    'resourceType' => '*',
    'folder' => '/',
    'folderView' => true,
    'folderCreate' => true,
    'folderRename' => true,
    'folderDelete' => true,
    'fileView' => true,
    'fileUpload' => true,
    'fileRename' => true,
    'fileDelete' => true);

    /*
    For example, if you want to restrict the upload, rename or delete of files inthe "Logos" folder of the resource type "Images", you may uncomment thefollowing definition, leaving the above one:

    $config['AccessControl'][] = Array(
    'role' => '*',
    'resourceType' => 'Images',
    'folder' => '/Logos',
    'folderView' => true,
    'folderCreate' => true,
    'folderRename' => true,
    'folderDelete' => true,
    'fileView' => true,
    'fileUpload' => false,
    'fileRename' => false,
    'fileDelete' => false);

    */
    /*
    ResourceType : defines the "resource types" handled in CKFinder.
    A resourcetype is nothing more than a way to group files under different paths, each onehaving different configuration settings.

    Each resource type name must be unique.

    When loading CKFinder, the "type" querystring parameter can be used to displaya specific type only.

    If "type" is omitted in the URL, the"DefaultResourceTypes" settings is used (may contain the resource type namesseparated by a comma).

    If left empty, all types are loaded.maxSize is defined in bytes, but shorthand notation may be also used.

    Available options are: G, M, K (case insensitive).1M equals 1048576 bytes (one Megabyte), 1K equals 1024 bytes (one Kilobyte), 1G equals one Gigabyte.Example: 'maxSize' => "8M",

    */

    $config['DefaultResourceTypes'] = '';
    $config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Files', // Single quotes not allowed
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'files',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'files',
    'maxSize' => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

    $config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Images',
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'images',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'images',
    'maxSize' => "16M",
    'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png,avi,iso,mp3',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

    $config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
    'name' => 'Flash',
    'url' => $baseUrl . 'flash',
    'directory' => $baseDir . 'flash',
    'maxSize' => 0,
    'allowedExtensions' => 'swf,flv',
    'deniedExtensions' => '');

    /* Due to security issues with Apache modules, it is recommended to leave the following setting enabled. How does it work?

    Suppose the following:
    - If "php" is on the denied extensions list, a file named foo.php cannot be   uploaded.
    - If "rar" (or any other) extension is allowed, one can upload a file named   foo.rar.
    - The file foo.php.rar has "rar" extension so, in theory, it can be also      uploaded.In some conditions Apache can treat the foo.php.rar file just like any PHPscript and execute it.

    If CheckDoubleExtension is enabled, each part of the file name after a dot ischecked, not only the last part. In this way, uploading foo.php.rar would bedenied, because "php" is on the denied extensions list.

    */

    $config['CheckDoubleExtension'] = true;

    /*If you have iconv enabled (visit http://php.net/iconv for more information),you can use this directive to specify the encoding of file names in yoursystem.

    Acceptable values can be found at:  http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

    Examples:
    $config['FilesystemEncoding'] = 'CP1250';

    $config['FilesystemEncoding'] = 'ISO-8859-2';

    */

    $config['FilesystemEncoding'] = 'UTF-8';

    /*
    Perform additional checks for image filesif set to true, validate image size
    */
    $config['SecureImageUploads'] = true;

    /*
    Indicates that the file size (maxSize) for images must be checked onlyafter scaling them. Otherwise, it is checked right after uploading.
    */
    $config['CheckSizeAfterScaling'] = true;

    /*
    For security, HTML is allowed in the first Kb of data for files having thefollowing extensions only.
    */
    $config['HtmlExtensions'] = array('html', 'htm', 'xml', 'js');

    /*
    Folders to not display in CKFinder, no matter their location.No paths are accepted, only the folder name.The * and ? wildcards are accepted.
    */
    $config['HideFolders'] = Array(".svn", "CVS");

    /*
    Files to not display in CKFinder, no matter their location.No paths are accepted, only the file name, including extension.The * and ? wildcards are accepted.
    */

    $config['HideFiles'] = Array(".*");

    /*
    After file is uploaded, sometimes it is required to change its permissionsso that it was possible to access it at the later time.
    If possible, it is recommended to set more restrictive permissions, like 0755.
    Set to 0 to disable this feature.Note: not needed on Windows-based servers.
    */

    $config['ChmodFiles'] = 0777;

    /*
    See comments above.Used when creating folders that does not exist.
    */

    $config['ChmodFolders'] = 0755;
    /*
    Force ASCII names for files and folders.
    If enabled, characters with diactric marks, like å, ä, ö, ć, č, đ, šwill be automatically converted to ASCII letters.
    */
    $config['ForceAscii'] = false;
    include_once "plugins/imageresize/plugin.php";
    include_once "plugins/fileeditor/plugin.php";
    $config['plugin_imageresize']['smallThumb'] = '90x90';
    $config['plugin_imageresize']['mediumThumb'] = '120x120';
    $config['plugin_imageresize']['largeThumb'] = '180x180';
```

[image: System error message]

This guy is having the exact same issue:

http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Ckfinder-blank-server-error-drupal...-my-whits-end

Comment: Check your write permissions in the directory.

Comment: The file directory or my CKFinder? Though I guess I can check both.

Comment: 775 (everything but write permissions for public) (for CKFinder) and 777 for files directory for Drupal.

Comment: can you try to check the value in $baseDir = resolveUrl($baseUrl);I am using this as $baseDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ckfinder/userfiles';

Comment: Not sure how I'd show that. Trying print_r() and it isn't showing up anywhere. I don't have server log access - what's the best way to get that information?

Comment: Try to put  $baseDir  as absolute path to your directory,Eg:$baseDir='C:/xammp/htdocs/project/ckfinder/userfiles';

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27566/discussion-between-shin-and-andrew-alexander)